# Turn a truth table derived from command line arguments into data types

Tags: haskell

The real-world code my problem stems from is much more complicated than the following example (consisting of several mock functions). This example should illustrate the phenomenon my problem produces: (either) a huge table in a `case`/`of` statement (or a huge cascade of nested `if`s). The `case`/`of` statement contains something similar to a truth table which decides how to parameterize the type of the result record (which is called `ComposedRecord` because it is a composition of three records of generic types). The mocked functions are already implemented, but I am not happy with the huge `case`/`of` block. Thus I am trying to find a more concise solution:

```
-- intermediate record type 1
data SimpleRecord = SimpleRecord {
  _description :: String
}

-- intermediate record type 2
data DetailedRecord = DetailedRecord {
  _title :: String,
  _details :: String
}

-- intermediate record type 3
data RawRecord = RawRecord {
  _x :: Int,
  _y :: Int,
  _z :: Int
}

class AnyRecord r where
instance AnyRecord SimpleRecord
instance AnyRecord DetailedRecord
instance AnyRecord RawRecord

-- to-be-serialized record type (composed of intermediate record types 1, 2 or 3)
data ComposedRecord a b c = ComposedRecord {
  _a :: a,
  _b :: b,
  _c :: c
}

inputToSimpleRecord :: String -> SimpleRecord
inputToSimpleRecord input = SimpleRecord {
  _description = "description derived from input"
}

inputToDetailedRecord :: String -> DetailedRecord
inputToDetailedRecord input = DetailedRecord {
  _title = "title derived from input",
  _details = "details derived from input"
}

inputToRawRecord :: String -> RawRecord
inputToRawRecord input = RawRecord {
  _x = 1, -- number derived from input string
  _y = 2, -- number derived from input string
  _z = 3  -- number derived from input string
}

serializeToJsonString :: (AnyRecord a, AnyRecord b, AnyRecord c) => ComposedRecord a b c -> String
serializeToJsonString composedRecord = "{}"
-- this function will also contain some post processing of the records
-- thus the "AnyRecord" type constraint is needed

commandLineArguments = ["simple", "detailed", "raw"]
-- the value of commandLineArguments will be read from the command line

inputFromCommandLine = "1, 2, 3" -- some input

main = do
  let result = case commandLineArguments of
        ["simple", "simple", "simple"] -> serializeToJsonString ComposedRecord {
          _a = inputToSimpleRecord inputFromCommandLine,
          _b = inputToSimpleRecord inputFromCommandLine,
          _c = inputToSimpleRecord inputFromCommandLine
        }
        ["simple", "simple", "detailed"] -> serializeToJsonString ComposedRecord {
          _a = inputToSimpleRecord inputFromCommandLine,
          _b = inputToSimpleRecord inputFromCommandLine,
          _c = inputToDetailedRecord inputFromCommandLine
        }
        ["simple", "simple", "raw"] -> serializeToJsonString ComposedRecord {
          _a = inputToSimpleRecord inputFromCommandLine,
          _b = inputToSimpleRecord inputFromCommandLine,
          _c = inputToRawRecord inputFromCommandLine
        }
        ["simple", "detailed", "simple"] -> serializeToJsonString ComposedRecord {
          _a = inputToSimpleRecord inputFromCommandLine,
          _b = inputToDetailedRecord inputFromCommandLine,
          _c = inputToSimpleRecord inputFromCommandLine
        }
        ["simple", "detailed", "detailed"] -> serializeToJsonString ComposedRecord {
          _a = inputToSimpleRecord inputFromCommandLine,
          _b = inputToDetailedRecord inputFromCommandLine,
          _c = inputToDetailedRecord inputFromCommandLine
        }
        ["simple", "detailed", "raw"] -> serializeToJsonString ComposedRecord {
          _a = inputToSimpleRecord inputFromCommandLine,
          _b = inputToDetailedRecord inputFromCommandLine,
          _c = inputToRawRecord inputFromCommandLine
        }
        ["simple", "raw", "raw"] -> serializeToJsonString ComposedRecord {
          _a = inputToSimpleRecord inputFromCommandLine,
          _b = inputToRawRecord inputFromCommandLine,
          _c = inputToRawRecord inputFromCommandLine
        }
        ["detailed", "simple", "simple"] -> serializeToJsonString ComposedRecord {
          _a = inputToDetailedRecord inputFromCommandLine,
          _b = inputToSimpleRecord inputFromCommandLine,
          _c = inputToSimpleRecord inputFromCommandLine
        }
        -- and so on...

  putStrLn result
```

Comment: I can't find any easy solution. In your code you involve 3^3 distinct types which makes this hard. Ideally, instead of building the 3^3 distinct `ComposedRecord a b c` types, and generate a `JSON` from that, one could instead define, for each of the 3 types (simple/raw/detailed) how to build a `JSON`, then make a triple of all the three `JSON`s, and finally combine those into a single `JSON`. Alternatively, one could try to exploit Template Haskell to generate all the 3^3 cases (which I guess can be a larger number in your actual production code).

Answer (score 2):

To me, the key element here is the type of `serializeToJsonString`.  That function doesn't care explicitly *which* `Record` it takes, so long as it is `AnyRecord`.  With that in mind, you can use `ExistentialQuantification` to encapsulate that idea.  Consider the following:

```hs
data AnyRecordData = forall r. AnyRecord r => AnyRecordData r

data ComposedRecord = ComposedRecord {
  _a :: AnyRecordData,
  _b :: AnyRecordData,
  _c :: AnyRecordData
}


inputToAnyRecord :: String -> String -> AnyRecordData
inputToAnyRecord "simple"   = AnyRecordData . inputToSimpleRecord
inputToAnyRecord "detailed" = AnyRecordData . inputToDetailedRecord
inputToAnyRecord "raw"      = AnyRecordData . inputToRawRecord

main = do
  let result = case commandLineArguments of
        [a,b,c] -> serializeToJsonString ComposedRecord {
          _a = inputToAnyRecord a inputFromCommandLine
        , _b = inputToAnyRecord b inputFromCommandLine
        , _c = inputToAnyRecord c inputFromCommandLine
        }

  putStrLn result
```

Comment: Possibly a good solution. But this is not using `-XRankNTypes`, it's using `-XExistentialQuantification`. And, obligatory reading for anyone dabbling with existentials: [Haskell antipattern: existential typeclass](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/)

Comment: @leftaroundabout Thanks for catching that — I've updated it in my answer.  Also, I completely agree that the post you linked is necessary reading.

Comment: You can, however, skip the intermediate existential data type by using `RankNTypes` & CPS: instead of returning any record, which would be spelled `String -> String -> exists r. AnyRecord r => r` if we had first-class existentials, you just accept a function that accepts any record: `String -> String -> (forall r. AnyRecord r => r -> x) -> x`.

Answer (score 1):

`ComposedRecord` is essentially a [heterogeneous list](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HList-0.5.0.0/docs/Data-HList-HList.html) type. So that's how I would approach it:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}

import Data.HList.HList

type ComposedRecord a b c = HList '[a,b,c]
```

Now you can start to think recursively over this container, although with a catch because the types change during the recursion.

```
class CRecSerialisable r where
  serializeToJsonString :: r -> String

instance CRecSerialisable (HList '[])
instance (AnyRecord h, CRecSerialisable (HList t))
    => CRecSerialisable (HList (h ': t))
        -- ▲ at this point enable any extensions the compiler demands...

serializeToJsStr_cmdDep :: [String] -> String
serializeToJsStr_cmdDep = go HNil
 where go :: CRecSerialisable acc => acc -> [String] -> String
       go cRec [] = serializeToJsonString cRec
       go cRec ("simple" : cmdArgs)
           = go (HCons (inputToSimpleRecord inputFromCommandLine) cRec)
                 cmdArgs
       go cRec ("detailed" : cmdArgs)
           = ...
```

Comment: This is a great solution if `serializeToJsonString` needs to behave differently for different record types.  It's not hard to just make multiple instances of the form `CRecSerialisable (HList (SimpleRecord ': t))` for each record type instead of the single instance with the `AnyRecord h` constraint.